# How to exclude a number from Random number of series?

Tags: java, animation, random, dice

I am developing a dice game. I am generating A random no, between 1 to 6. and my dice showing same no. So it is working perfectly. But after a condition, I want that, 2 must not be come, so how can I remove 2 between 1 to 6. Here is my code.

```
Random rng = new Random();
btnSpin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!rolling) {
                dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice3d);
                timer.schedule(new Roll(), 400);
            }
        }
    });
}

// code of dice...
class Roll extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

Callback callback = new Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (rng.nextInt(6) + 1) {
        case 1:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
            icon = "one";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The value is one" + one, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
            icon = "two";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The value is two" + two, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 3:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
            icon = "three";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The value is three" + three, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        case 4:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
            icon = "four";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The value is four" + four, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 5:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
            icon = "five";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The value is five" + five, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 6:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.six);
            icon = "six";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The value is six" + six, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
        }
        rolling = false; // user can press again
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You can create a list of values not allowed, and while the value is something in that list, keep creating a new random number. However, you might want to check there exists valid numbers so that you are not stuck in an eternal loop (like random between 1-6, when 1-6 are not allowed).

Comment: Actually I just want that 2 must not be come after a condition is true, but 1,3,4,5,6 can be come.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first fill a list with the allowed values and then generate a random index in the bounds of this list.

```
List<Integer> allowedValues = Arrays.asList(1,3,4,5,6);
Random rd = new Random();
int selected = allowedValues(rd.nextInt(allowedValues.size()));
```

Comment: You probably meant `int selected = allowedValues.get(rd.nextInt(allowedValues.size()));`.

Comment: `allowedValues` is not a function, this is still incorrect and does not compile.